# SSL not working in jmeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter

Getting exception when visiting my app in view results tree:
Response message: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

1. Added Thread group.
2. Added HTTP request defaults with my application server address to thread group.
3. Added Recording controller to thread group.
4. Added HTTP(S) Test script recorder for workbench.
5. Added View Results Tree for recorder.
6. Started recorder with port 8123, including .*.xhtml and excluding ..*js, ..*png
7. Configured proxy in firefox with localhost and 8123 port.
8. Accepted jmeter dummy certificate.

Certificate only visible in servers section of firefox certificates configuration. It is not visible in authorities section.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a CA problem.

Have you read [this?](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

> 13. Return to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, and click the “Start” button at the bottom. This will start the JMeter proxy server which is
>       used to intercept the browser requests. A file called
>       ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt will be generated in jmeter/bin
>       folder. Install this certificate in your browser, if you don't know
>       how to do it, read “Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS
>       recording” in : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Comment: For me, ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt is not generated. Using jdk-8u66-windows-x64. Only the proxyserver.jks file is generated

Comment: @Cagy79 - Did you try the suggestion from the documentation that says you can force the regeneration of the keystore and certificate if you delete the 'proxyserver.jks' file? .. also.. if that's the problem then it might deserve it's own separate question?